# How to set an different grid cols for md and below screen?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind to display grid. I want the grid to be `grid-cols-3` for large screen and above,
and `grid-cols-2` for medium screen and below.

Currently I'm using `class="grid grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-2"` which is not working.

The `md:grid-cols-2` is overriding for all screen size.
How can I set different grid size for different screen size